# Start NSTextFieldCell editing by button click

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, editing, nstextfieldcell

I need to start `NSTextFieldCell` editing after button clicked (the same behaviour if user double click on the cell)

I found a function `performClick` which simulates user clicking by cursor. My idea is to call a simulation of **double** clicking. Does this function exist?Or maybe you can suggest other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)editclicked:(id)sender{
    NSInteger col = [dreamTable columnWithIdentifier:@"data"];
    NSInteger row = [dreamTable selectedRow];
    [dreamTable editColumn:col row:row withEvent:NULL select:YES];
}
```

This is a solution